# Catch Response Returned from a method which implements Runnable

Tags: java, spring-boot, executorservice, runnable

I have implemented Executor Service in my code

```
 ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 Runnable r;
 String timeout='30000';

try {
            if (condA)) {
                r = () -> classA.execute(request);
            } else {
                 r = () -> classB.execute(request);
            }
            Future<?> f = service.submit(r);
           f.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);    
        } catch (final TimeoutException e) {
            throw some exception;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
           throw e.getCause();
            
        } finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }
```

Class A and Class B returns another classC with some confirmation number .

this is the code snippet of the execute method in each of ClassA and classB

```
public static ClassC execute(Request r) {
return ClassC.builder()
        .confirmationNumber("123456").build();
}
```

How can I access the confirmation number in the calling service ?

Comment: [`Future.get(long timeout,TimeUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) returns an instance of  `ClassC` for you to use ...

Comment: ... which makes the use of Executor somewhat senseless. You hand the computation off to ExecutorService and then you _wait_ for it to finish right away...

Comment: Future.get(long timeout,TimeUnit unit) is returning null

Comment: Then something is wrong in your `execute` implementation. You are expecting it to return an instance of ClassC, so I'd debug your ClassC-Builder.